# Trying to understand object and method creation in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I'm trying to understand the different ways to create objects and methods in javascript. I've read a lot of articles, blogs and stackoverflow questions and I think I get the notion in general. But I've encountered a small javascript library (written in coffeescript) and the the way it creates objects and methods confused me a little.

I've included a snippet but if you want you can find the complete script at [instafeed.js](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/blob/master/instafeed.js).

Code:

```
(function() {
    var Instafeed, root;

    Instafeed = (function() {

        function Instafeed(params) {
            var option, value;
            this.options = {
                target: 'instafeed',
                get: 'popular',
                resolution: 'thumbnail',
                sortBy: 'most-recent',
                links: true,
                limit: 15,
                mock: false
            };
            if (typeof params === 'object') {
                for (option in params) {
                  value = params[option];
                  this.options[option] = value;
                }
            }
        }

        Instafeed.prototype.run = function() {
            var header, instanceName, script;
            if (typeof this.options.clientId !== 'string') {
                if (typeof this.options.accessToken !== 'string') {
                  throw new Error("Missing clientId or accessToken.");
                }
            }
            if (typeof this.options.accessToken !== 'string') {
                if (typeof this.options.clientId !== 'string') {
                  throw new Error("Missing clientId or accessToken.");
                }
            }
            if ((this.options.before != null) && typeof this.options.before === 'function') {
                this.options.before.call(this);
            }
            if (typeof document !== "undefined" && document !== null) {
                script = document.createElement('script');
                script.id = 'instafeed-fetcher';
                script.src = this._buildUrl();
                header = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
                header[0].appendChild(script);
                instanceName = "instafeedCache" + this.unique;
                window[instanceName] = new Instafeed(this.options);
                window[instanceName].unique = this.unique;
            }
            return true;
        }

    ...

        return Instafeed;

    })();

    root = typeof exports !== "undefined" && exports !== null ? exports : window;

    root.Instafeed = Instafeed;

}).call(this);
```

I'm having difficulties understanding the following:

1. Why did the author prefer to wrap everything with `(function(){...}).call(this);`? Maybe to avoid creating global variables?
2. What purpose does the `.call(this)` part at the very end of the script serve?
3. Why did the author create the `root` variable and what are the following lines for?

   ```
   root = typeof exports !== "undefined" && exports !== null ? exports : window;
   root.Instafeed = Instafeed;
   ```

Since this the preferred way to create objects and methods in coffeescript I suppose this is one of the better ways to do it. But its advantages over the following version escapes me:

```
function Instafeed(params) {
    ...
}
Instafeed.prototype.run = function() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes; this makes all formerly top-level `var`s into local variables.
2. It makes `this` equal to the global object inside the function
3. It lets it work as a [CommonJS module](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1.1) (for Node.js or Browserify)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do you have any comments on the last part? (Advantages over common way...)

Comment: @monroo: Advantages of which differences?